# How to check if a sub attribute in mongoDB exists using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

Im trying to check in a sub attribute in mongodb using pymongo if it exists before printing them out since normally, the program would output an error if i print an attribute that does not exist.

I can do something like this to check if an attribute in the higher level exists

```
for x in raw200k.find({},{attrib1}):
    if 'attrib1' in x:
        print x[attrib1]
    else
        print 'does not exist.'
```

However this attrib1 has sub attributes inside it. Something like:

```
attrib1:{
    subattrib1: "value"
}
```

I want something like this:

```
for x in raw200k.find({},{attrib1.subattrib1}):
    if 'attrib1.subattrib1' in x:
        print x[attrib1.subattrib1]
    else
        print 'does not exist.'
```

Although the above code does not have an error, it also doesn't print anything even though subattrib1 exists.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not urgently and desperately migrating your code to the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3?

Comment: @tripleee the old code is written in python 2.7 so we are required to continue coding in python 2.7

Comment: Fair enough, but you are increasingly unlikely to receive help for this obsolescent version.